# Failed to locate or generate matching signing assets "Xcode 6"

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, ad-hoc-distribution

After archive success when i click on Export button one window is appearing and saying

> "Failed to locate or generate matching signing assets"

See the below screen shot:

[image]

Can anybody tell me how to solve this?

Thanks in advance

---

### **PS:** I have 110 devices registred under my apple ID "Not 100", I've asked apple to reset the devices, but they refused, and they give me a solution to add 10 more devices to my account.

Comment: The yellow triangle means a warning and I'm not convinced that's the true problem. Do you have your private and public key installed in Keychain Access on that machine?  Do you have your provisioning profile downloaded?

Comment: Everything is as usual, the only new thing is that I've requested apple for more test devices "More than 100", and now i have 110 device registered under my apple ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, just disable some of devices and keep the number of devices registered under 100.